# dropdown index change with sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception 500

Tags: drop-down-menu, delegates, updatepanel, updatepanel-progressbar

I used delegates.In delegate, i am using dropdown list index changing event. i am calling this into one aspx page.In running time it getting error.( Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500).I tried to find out error by using break point.every function is work correctly.after the page unload method it getting error.And I tried button event instead of dropdown index change.that is working.but I want dropdown index changing event.How can I solve this problem?please tell me the solution